# Is it illegal to ask nudes even though we both are underaged

Tags: united-kingdom

I wanted to ask if it's legal to ask for someone for nudes even though she and I are underaged and she started asking for 'dirty' stuff first . Thank you in advance
I'm in the UK btw

Comment: You mean _pictures_ with you or your GF nude? Or do you want to see her nude, but in person?

Comment: I don't know the UK legal system, but you may want to define "underage" a bit better. In the legal systems I do know, two 16 year olds trading nudes is a totally different case from a 17 year old asking a 12 year old for example. Neither might be a good idea, but they are fundamentally different as far as the law is concerned.

Comment: Me and her are both 14 and a picture

Answer (score 3):

### 100% illegal

Maximum 10-years-jail-time and sex-offender-register-for-life illegal.

The Protection of Children Act 1978, makes it illegal to take, make, distribute, show, or possess for the intent of showing or distributing an indecent photograph of someone under the age of 18. That includes taking photos of yourself if you are under 18.